# PWM using Fixed Point - Xilinx

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, fixed-point, pwm

I just started to program in VHDL using Xilinx (ISE 14.7). I already could program some projects, but I'm struggling to do this one. My research teacher ask for a PWM using fixed point. I manage to use both separately, but I had some errors and now I can't know what is causing the actual problem. The errors are :

> HDLCompiler:579 - "C:\Users\student\Desktop\Guilherme Moitas\Projects\pwm_fp\pwm_fp.vhd" Line 48: Mismatch in number of elements assigned in conditional signal assignment
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:410 - "C:\Users\student\Desktop\Guilherme Moitas\Projects\pwm_fp\pwm_fp.vhd" Line 48: Expression has 18 elements ; expected 17

And this is the code I made it:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
library ieee_proposed;
use ieee_proposed.fixed_pkg.all;

entity pwm_fp is
Port (      clk      : in  STD_LOGIC;
         reset    : in  STD_LOGIC; 
         button_l : in  STD_LOGIC;  
         button_r : in  STD_LOGIC; 
         pwm      : out  STD_LOGIC);
 end pwm_fp;

 architecture Behavioral of pwm_fp is
  signal period:ufixed (12 downto -4);
  signal dcycle_max: ufixed (9 downto -4);
  signal dcycle_min: ufixed (8 downto -4);
  signal duty_in: ufixed (4 downto -4);
  signal pwm_reg,pwm_next:std_logic;
  signal duty_cycle,duty_cycle_next: ufixed (9 downto -4);
  signal counter,counter_next:ufixed (12 downto -4);
  signal tick:std_logic;
    --signal x: ufixed (12 downto -4);
 begin
 --register
     process(clk,reset)
          begin
               if reset = '1' then 
                    pwm_reg<='0';
                    counter<="00000000000000000";
                    duty_cycle<="00000000000000";
               elsif clk='1' and clk'event then
                     pwm_reg<=pwm_next;
                     counter<=counter_next;
                     duty_cycle<=duty_cycle_next;
               end if;
         end process;
                period <= to_ufixed (1001110001000.0000, period);
                dcycle_max <= to_ufixed (1000.00, dcycle_max);
                dcycle_min <= to_ufixed (500.00, dcycle_min);
                duty_in <= to_ufixed (20.00, duty_in);
                duty_cycle <= to_ufixed (0, duty_cycle);
                duty_cycle_next <= to_ufixed (0, duty_cycle_next);
                counter <= to_ufixed (000000000000.0000, counter);
                counter_next <= to_ufixed (0000000000000.0000,counter_next);
                --x <= to_ufixed (0000000000001.0000, x);

 counter_next <= "0" when counter = period else  -- this is line 48
                     counter + 1 ;
 tick<= '1' when counter= 0 else
         '0';

 --Changing Duty Cycle 
 process(button_l,button_r,tick,duty_cycle) 
    begin
         duty_cycle_next<=duty_cycle;
          if tick='1' then
               if button_l ='1' and (duty_cycle >dcycle_min) then
                      duty_cycle_next<= (duty_cycle-duty_in); 
               elsif button_r ='1' and (duty_cycle < dcycle_max) then
                      duty_cycle_next<= (duty_cycle+duty_in);
              end if;              
        end if;                            
 end process;
 --Buffer
 pwm<=pwm_reg;     
 pwm_next<= '1' when counter < duty_cycle else
                    '0';    
 end Behavioral;
```

I hope you can help me, and sorry about any dumb mistake. Since now, thanks!

Comment: The `when .. else` expression is like a ternary operator. It expects both assignable values to be of equal size, but one input is of length 1 (`"0"`) and the other of length 17 (`counter + 1`).

Comment: What is the benefit of using fixed point arithmetic compared to `integer` or `unsigned` for a PWM module? Btw, your design creates multiple drivers e.g. for `counter`, `duty_cycle`, `counter_next`, `duty_cycle_next`. You can see them, when you correct your indentation.

Comment: The 18 elements comes from the ufixed "+" operator whose result length is one greater than the (converted) length of  either operand.

Comment: Ok, I could resolve the mismatching number problem! Thanks Paebbels, I asked my professor to give you the benefit of using that if has any. And what the problem with the multiple drivers? I'm sorry but I'm very new at VHDL. Now I'm just having problem with the 18 elements; expected 17. I need to do this addition for counting.

Comment: @Paebbels this is the answer my professor gave to me:The benefit is in floating point I cannot make all the operations that I want to do.
- PWM (6 to 8 channels at least) or - SVM (6 to 8 channels at least)
- Acquisition (8 channels at least), that requieres to pass the data from serial to parallel and adecuate the data to the controller.
- Interruptions (one)
As you can see I need 8 modulations, 8 ADC plus more activities in the FPGA.
The quantity of FF is not going to be enought if the code is made in floating point.
Thus, fix point will programming space to introduce all this code.

Comment: Having multiple drivers on a signal in synthesis is like having a short in a circuit. For example, `counter` is always assigned with `to_ufixed(0.0)`, but then your sequential process updates the signal too. What values shall it use, 0.0 or the incremented counter value? Regarding FixedPoint. I didn't mean to use FloatingPoint :). But using the datatypes `unsigned` or `integer` or `natural` might be simpler. As far as I see, all your calculations don't use the fractional parts.

Comment: @Paebbels My calculations didn't have because I used my first pwm project as base to this one, but my professor said that we are goingo to use fractional parts, like numbers between 0 and 1. I used the  `to_ufixed` just because I thougth I had to define before I program, since it was giving me errors when I start the Changing Duty Cycle. I tried resize `counter` to 18, but it didn't allow me also.